# write a stories test with Storybook for a component having props typed with discriminated union type

Tags: typescript, next.js, storybook

I need to write a test with Storybook for my Button component which has the "props" typed with a discriminated union type.

I am using:

- Nextjs: 13.4.10
- storybook: 7.1.1
- typescript": 5.1.6

My Button component code:

```
type ButtonRect = {
  shape?: "rect";
  text: string;
  isLoading?: boolean;
  icon?: ButtonIconName | ReactElement;
  iconPosition?: "left" | "right" | "both";
};

type ButtonCircle = {
  shape: "circle";
  icon: ButtonIconName | ReactElement;
};

type ButtonCommon = {
  type?: "button" | "submit";
  onClick?: () => void;
  color: ButtonColor;
  disabled?: boolean;
  title?: string;
  display?: Display;
  backgroundType?: BackgroundType;
};

type Props = (ButtonRect | ButtonCircle) & ButtonCommon;

export function Button(props: Props) {...}
```

My test:

```
import type { Meta, StoryObj } from "@storybook/react";
import { Button } from "./Button";

const meta: Meta<typeof Button> = {
  title: "inputs/Button",
  component: Button,
} satisfies Meta<typeof Button>;

export default meta;

type Story = StoryObj<typeof meta>;

export const primary: Story = {
  args: { // return the error message: The expected type comes from property 'args' which is declared here on type 'StoryAnnotations<ReactRenderer, never, never>'
    color: "primary", 
    type: "button", 
    disabled: false, 
    title: "click for ...", 
    onClick: () => console.log("clicked!"), 
    display: "auto", 
    backgroundType: "filled", 
    shape: "rect", 
    text: "CLICCAMI", 
    isLoading: false, 
    icon: "product", 
    iconPosition: "left", 
  },
};
```

I would write a proper test that covers the case of a component with props typed with discriminated union type